# How to calculate area under peaks by using trapz in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I am newbie in matlab and have an issue with calculating area under peaks. Here are the codes that I use to find the peaks :

```
%% Peak flow analysis 2 (Figure 3)
flowtable = finalCSVnew(:,[1,7:8]);                                         % create table containing DateAndTime, Durchflusslm, and SummeaktuellerTagm data

peakflowEvent = flowtable{:,2} > aa ;                                        % determine the threshold of flow(m3/h) for peakflowEvent

% use false as logical vector to determine transition. With function diff, 
% transitions from false (0) to true (1) will be 1 and transitions from true
% to false will be -1. This will be 1 at the start of a dry period and -1 after the end
peakTransitions = diff([false; peakflowEvent; false]);                             
eventStarts = find(peakTransitions == 1);
eventEnds = find(peakTransitions == -1) -1;

% define the peak flow of each event through the flow data (peakflow) and
% the time when peak flow is happened (peakflowtime)
[peakflow, peakflowlocrel] = arrayfun(@(s, e) max(flowtable.Durchflusslm(s:e)), eventStarts, eventEnds);
peakflowlocabs = peakflowlocrel + eventStarts - 1;
peakflowtime=flowtable.DateAndTime(peakflowlocabs);

% create result table containing start and end time for peak flow event, the duration
% between start and end time, and peak flow
peakflowanalysis2 = table(flowtable.DateAndTime(eventStarts), flowtable.DateAndTime(eventEnds), ...
                 flowtable.DateAndTime(eventEnds) - flowtable.DateAndTime(eventStarts), ...
                 peakflow, peakflowtime, ...
                 'VariableNames', {'Start', 'End', 'Duration','PeakFlow','PeakFlowTime'});

numPeakflow2 = height(peakflowanalysis2);                                   % calculate the number of max flow

% plot flow and peak flow
figure(3)
plot(flowtable.DateAndTime,flowtable.Durchflusslm,flowtable.DateAndTime(peakflowlocabs),peakflow,'v','MarkerFaceColor','red',...
    'MarkerSize',5)
xlabel('Date and Time');                                                    % define Date and Time as x-axis
ylabel('Flow [m3/h]');                                                      % define Flow as y-axis
title('Peak Flow Events (2)');                                              % define the title of the plot
legend('Flow','Peak Flow','Location','Northeast','Orientation','Vertical')
grid on                                                                     % show grid on plot
datacursormode on                                                           % enable to display data value interactively in the plot

% clear temporary variables
clearvars peakflowEvent peakTransitions eventStarts eventEnds peakflowlocrel peakflowlocabs peakflow peakflowtime
```

It produce two tables and one figure. The figure which contain peaks and also represent each event. The number of peaks = the number of event
[image: figure]
The table contains original data :
[image: flowtable]
This table below contain the filtered data where they have peaks
[image: peakflowanalysis2]
[image: error]

I want to know how to calculate the area under peaks for each event (11 events), and not sum of all. I read about trapz() but I got confused how to apply it for multiple peaks. Could you please help me? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't store large datasets in tables, they are very slow. I work with a lot of hydrological data and always use an numeric array for the data and a numeric array (as datenum) for the timeseries.

To get the area under the peak use trapz and loop over each of your flood peaks:

```
time_start=datenum(Peakflowanalysis.Start,'dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM:SS');
time_end=datenum(Peakflowanalysis.Ende,'dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM:SS');
time_array=datenum(flowtable.DateandTime,'dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM:SS');

for i=1:height(peakflow)
ind1=find(time_array==time_start)
ind2=find(time_array==time_end)
peak_sum(i)=trapz(flowdata(Start(ind1):Ende(ind2)));% trapz method
peak_sum(i,2)=sum(flowdata(Start(ind1):Ende(ind2)));%sum method
end
```

Before, you need to convert your start and end to indices of your flowdata.

Also try using the sum method, too. you will see that it is very similar to your trapz results, depending of the timeresolution of your data.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Squeezie. I am sorry I still do not get it about converting the start and end to my flowdata. Could you please explain more about it?

Comment: Trapz require a vector as input. Since you only got one big vector, you need to provice the indices for the start and end of each your flood events. It seems you only got thestart and end dates as a string You need to find the indice in your vector when the even starts and ends. It will work with strings but isway slower than when you use datenum and convert your strings into numerical data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I apply your method above, however I got an errror "Error using datetime/datenum
Too many input arguments."

Comment: Did you check if all variables have been written correctly by me?
Also you might need to convert the date strings in the table to a cellarray and/or run it with cellfun.

Comment: yes, I modify the variable a bit based on the data. I uploaded the fourth picture above regarding the error I got. So I need to convert the datetime to cellarray by using the cellfun? not using datenum?

Comment: That's why i try to use as less tables as possible, they mostly are hard to use for functions. Convert your timeseries to a cellarray of strings. then make this cellarray of strings into a datenum vector.

Comment: I have managed to convert the datetime to number (as double), when I run ind1 and ind2, there is an error "matrix dimensions must agree". Do you know why it happens? I uploaded the error picture above

Comment: Either you run the function inside a loop or use a arrayfun to determine those before the loop. What you are doing right now is you find a number of vectors within another vector, but FIND only can look for one number at a time but your time_start is nother vector. it should only be one number.